# Split list into array using delimiter element

Tags: python

I have a file containing data in this form:

```
Foo
http://url.com
http://url2.com

FooBar
http://url3.com

FooBarBar
http://url9.com
```

I want to treat every n lines as an element seperately. So after each line with only a `\n` I want to handle the following string and urls (number of urls varies). I create a folder with the name of the first string, then download the files from the urls.

I am using the following line to get a list of lines.

```
elements = list(open('C:\\filename.txt'))
```

Now I was thinking of getting this in an list of lists, where the `\n` is used as  a delimiter element.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: tried iterating through the lines with check for empty line?

Comment: can you show us an example of the list you have got so far

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't one line this type of problem because you aren't closing the file:

```
with open('C:\\filename.txt', 'r') as f:

    result = [] # This will keep track of the final output
    entry = [] # This will be our temporary entry that we will add to the result

    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip() # remove the new line stuff
        if not line and entry: # If it is not an empty line and our entry actually has stuff in it
            result.append(' '.join(entry))
            entry = []
        else:
            entry.append(line)
    if entry:
        result.append(' '.join(entry)) # Add the last entry.

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Foo http://url.com http://url2.com', ' FooBar http://url3.com', 'FooBarBar http://url9.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate over the lines in the file, and handle each case separately.

```
def urlsFromFile(path):
    files = {}
    with open(path) as f:  # Important to use with here to ensure file is closed after reading
        fileName = None
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip('\n')  # Remove \n from end of line
            if not line:  # If the line is empty reset the fileName
                fileName = None
            elif fileName is None:  # If fileName is None, then we previously reached a new line. Set the new fileName
                fileName = line
                files[fileName] = []
            else:  # We are working through the urls
                files[fileName].append(line)
    return files

print(urlsFromFile('filename.txt'))
```

Output:

```
{'FooBar': ['http://url3.com'], 'Foo': ['http://url.com', 'http://url2.com'], 'FooBarBar': ['http://url9.com']}
```

This will allow you to use the result to create directories and download the files in each list, for example:

```
for folder, urls in urlsFromFile('filename.txt').items():
    print('create folder {}'.format(folder))
    for url in urls:
        print('download {} to folder {}'.format(url, folder))
```

Output:

```
create folder FooBar
download http://url3.com to folder FooBar
create folder Foo
download http://url.com to folder Foo
download http://url2.com to folder Foo
create folder FooBarBar
download http://url9.com to folder FooBarBar
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is consistent, then you can simply read the file as a whole and split the string like you desire.

**CODE**

```python
with open('C:\\filename.txt') as fobj:
    elements = [block.split('\n') for block in fobj.read().split('\n\n')]
```

elements :=

```
[['Foo', 'http://url.com', 'http://url2.com'],
['FooBar', 'http://url3.com'],
['FooBarBar', 'http://url9.com']]
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

I always recommend using a context manager (`with`-statement). Because it is more safe in terms of data stream handling.

We have three layers here:

1. `fobj.read()` 
   The whole content of the file is buffered into a string.
2. `.split('\n\n')` 
   The former string is split by the delimiter of two consecutive newlines, resulting as a list of text blocks.
3. `block.split('\n')` 
   Every of those blocks is split into its lines.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative approach according to requirement *"create a folder with the name of the first string, then download the files from the urls."*:

```
import os

with open('input.txt') as f:
    folder_name = None
    folder_failed = False

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            if not line.startswith('http'):
                try:
                    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), line))
                    folder_name = line
                except OSError:
                    print(f"Creation of the directory `{line}` failed")
                    folder_failed = True
                else:
                    folder_failed = False
            elif not folder_failed:
                # downloading file
                new_file = download_file_from_url(line)  # replace with your custom function
                # save file into a folder `folder_name`
```